# Shell-like program C

Tags: c

The code below is supposed to work as a shell. It has the previous and next option, a history like feature, the exit and the execute command.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#define BUFFER_SIZE 256
#define HISTORY_LENGTH 128

int executeCommand(char*cmd)
{
    return(!strcmp(cmd,"e\n"));
}

int exitCommand(char*cmd)
{
    return (!strcmp(cmd,"exit\n"));
}

int previousCommand(char*cmd)
{
    return (!strcmp(cmd,"p\n"));
}

int nextCommand(char*cmd)
{
    return (!strcmp(cmd,"n\n"));
}

void execute(char *line)
{
    line[strlen(line)-1]='\0';
    char **arguments;
    char* temp;
    int i=0;
    arguments=(char**)malloc(sizeof(char)*10);
    temp=strtok(line," ");
    arguments[i]=malloc(strlen(temp)*sizeof(char));
    if(arguments[i]!=NULL)
    {
        strcpy(arguments[i],temp);
        i++;
    }
    else
    {
        printf("Out of memory");
    }
    while(temp!=NULL)
    {
        temp=strtok(NULL," ");
        if(temp==NULL){
            arguments[i]=NULL;
        }
        else{
            arguments[i]=malloc(strlen(temp)*sizeof(char));
            if(arguments[i]!=NULL)
            {
                strcpy(arguments[i],temp);
                i++;
            }
        }
    }
    printf("%s  ",arguments[0]);
    printf("%s  ",arguments[1]);
    printf("%s  ",arguments[2]);
    execvp(arguments[0],arguments);
}

int main(int argc, char*argV[]) {
    int i;
    char *cmd=(char*)malloc(sizeof(char)*BUFFER_SIZE);
    char **history=NULL;
    int historylength=0;
    int currentCommand=0;
    history=(char**)malloc(sizeof(char)*BUFFER_SIZE);
    do{
        fgets(cmd,BUFFER_SIZE-1,stdin);
        if(exitCommand(cmd))
            break;
        else
            if(previousCommand(cmd))
            {
                if(currentCommand>0)
                    printf("%s",history[--currentCommand]);
                else if(currentCommand==0)
                {
                    currentCommand=historylength;
                    printf("%s",history[--currentCommand]);
                }
            }
            else
                if(nextCommand(cmd))
                {
                    if(currentCommand<historylength)
                        printf("%s",history[currentCommand++]);
                }
                else
                    if(executeCommand(cmd))
                    {
                        execute(history[--currentCommand]);
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        history[historylength]=malloc(strlen(cmd)*sizeof(char));
                        if(history[historylength]!=NULL)
                        {
                            strcpy(history[historylength],cmd);
                            currentCommand=++historylength;
                        }
                        else
                        {
                            printf("Out of memory");
                            break;
                        }
                    }

    } while(1);

    free(cmd);

    for(i=0;i<historylength;i++)
        free(history[i]);
    free(history);

    return 0;
}
```

I want to make this work for the function cat. I type in the e cat main.c and I expect it to execute the cat command but it's not doing anything, what am I doing wrong here? I'm not a pro at this so I appreciate all the help.

Comment: Since you are new to C, one thing that can help with your readability is to use "else if" instead of an else block with an if in the block.   It would reduce your nesting levels and make your code more readable.

Comment: I thing you should introduce some better indentation for your code because your `if/ else if` construction is extremely unreadable. Also when you decompose your logic into smaller pieces it is easier to find a bug.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is incorrect:

```
arguments=(char**)malloc(sizeof(char)*10);
```

as `arguments` is a `char**`, so the code needs to allocate `sizeof(char*)`. Change to:

```
arguments = malloc(10 * sizeof(*arguments));
```

Same mistake for `history` also. Additionally, see [Do I cast the result of malloc?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/605845/do-i-cast-the-result-of-malloc)

There is one `char` less than required being allocated for the `char*` as `strcpy()` writes a terminating null character. Change:

```
arguments[i]=malloc(strlen(temp)*sizeof(char));
```

to:

```
arguments[i] = malloc(strlen(temp) + 1);
```

`sizeof(char)` is guaranteed to be `1` and can be omitted from the size calculation.

Prevent `i` from exceeding the bounds of the memory allocated for `arguments`. As the code currently stands there is no protection to prevent `i` from exceeding `9` (`0` to `9` are the valid values for `i` as `arguments` was allocated `10` elements).

Comment: By preventing you mean stating in the code that $i< args$ or just make sure not to type in more than 10?

Comment: Add `i < 10` to the `while` loop terminating condition.

Comment: I've made all the changes you suggested but when it comes to the cat command, it stays the same. What should I do to make it execute it?